# HTML problem, only works in Webkit

Tags: firefox, html

This works fine in Webkit, but when I go to Firefox (Or IE8) it totally messed up. I've been staring at this for so long that I can't find any errors at all with it, so maybe one of you guys can point out where I'm going wrong.

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #222;
}


header {
    background: #fff url('images/header-border.gif') bottom repeat-x;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}


section {   
}


article {


}


footer {
    clear: left;
}

nav {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, serif;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #060606;
}

#content {
    width: 980px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 155px;
}

#left-column, #logo {
    width: 560px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
}

#right-column, #share {
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

address {
    display: inline;
}

a img {
    border: 0px;
}

.clear-left {
    clear: left;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>Webtint </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/clean/style.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/xmlrpc.php" />

</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">tutorials <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/clean/images/arrow.gif" alt="Arrow" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">resources <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/clean/images/arrow.gif" alt="Arrow" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">articles <img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/clean/images/arrow.gif" alt="Arrow" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">follow us</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>


<header>

    <section id="logo">
        &nbsp;
    </section>

    <section id="share">
        &nbsp;
    </section>

</header>
<div id="content">

    <section id="left-column">  
        <article>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <time><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time> by <address><?php the_author(); ?></address>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <br /><br />
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a> 
        <?php comments_popup_link(
        '<span class="boxed">No Responses &#187;</span>', 
        '<span class="boxed"> 1 Response &#187;</span>',
        '<span class="boxed">% Responses &#187;</span>'); ?>
    </article>
    <hr />
    </section>


    <section id="right-column">

             <h2>Popular Posts</h2>

    </section>  


</div>
<footer>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot in Firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Abl.gif

Screenshot in Chrome: (How it's supposed to look)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NICpJ.gif

Screenshot in IE8:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YRwX.gif

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a debug tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) to figure out which elements are being placed wrongly and why.

Both let you hover your mouse over blocks and will highlight the corresponding HTML. You will be able to see exactly which element it is that is being placed incorrectly, and view the CSS to try and figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you're using mostly HTML5 specific elements, and they're not supported everywhere properly yet, especially IE8 out of those you listed.

For a quick look, [Here's the list of elements added in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#new-elements).

Comment: Okay, basically what happened was I thought that the browsers would have the support to know that things like <header> and <section> were block elements. I fixed it by just adding display: block; to all the HTML elements :)

Comment: +1 Nice one. Personally, I think this deserves to be the "answer", you actually spotted what the problem was, I just suggested a few common tools that could help.

Comment: @simon - Cheers :)  Long as Johnny's up and going is all that matters!

Answer (score 0):

Johnny, does your solution also fix the incorrect rendering in Firefox 2 and Camino 1? Interesting, as I only know of the Javascript solution. Just to give you some more feedback on this: to learn more about getting HTML5 rendered properly in all major browsers, read [this article](http://www.hagenburger.net/2009/03/html5-xhtml5-with-css-for-safari-firefox-opera-ie) by Nico Hagenburger. You can also use [this script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) to render HTML5 in IE.

A more general article about HTML5 and CSS3 support in IE (e.g., your corners aren't rounded) in [this article](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-ways-to-make-internet-explorer-act-like-a-modern-browser). For rounded corners in all major browsers (also in Opera) please read [this one](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers). There also exist [general tables](http://www.hagenburger.net/2009/05/4-useful-html5-browser-support-overviews) about support in all major browsers of HTML5 and CSS3.

EDIT: I just read an article about HTML5 pages not rendered properly when printing from within IE, because [this JavaScript solution](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) isn't loaded when printing a page. More info on [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/arent-my-media-declarations-recognized-properly-across-browsers#answer_2910).